# Destroy static_casted derived class before destroying base class

Tags: c++

```
class A{
    someFunctionOfA(){}
};
class B:public A{
    someFunctionOfB(){}
};
int main()
{
    WorldObject w;
    B *b;
    b = static_cast<B*>( w.createA() ); // returns pointer to class A
    b->someFunctionOfB();
    b->someFunctionOfA();
    //delete b; //still gives error
    w.end(); //destroys instance of base class A
} //tries to destroy instance of B but generates error
```

How to destroy instance of B without destroying A?
Or destroy both of them without error?
Is the downcast valid?

Comment: I don't understand. You create an `A` then you try to treat it as a `B`? You want to "destroy instance of `B`" but it doesn't look like you actually have one mate!

Comment: This code makes no sense to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  it looks like `w.createA()` returns an instance of `A`

Comment: One could assume the function `createA` creates the `A` by using `new`. Under this assumption the pointer should be deleted as an `A`

Comment: @Shan: Right, so where is the "instance of `B`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is ilegal ! You cannot convert a base class to a subclass  and expect the class to work like the sub class (I'm imagining that createA creates an object of type A and not an object of type B converted to A !).

For Q1 :
What you want is composition, and for that A should keep a pointer to B and instead of inheritance :

```
class A
{
   private: 
   B* m_pBComponent;
}
```

Then you can delete only B while keeping A.
You cannot delete only the derived part of a derived object.

Q2 : 
Make destructor virtual (not really necessary, unless you have custom allocation in A's constructor, but it's still best practice).

Make sure that createA returns an object of type B.

Q3 :

See ILoveCoding's Answer.

Comment: I used composition. but then i had to make identical functions of the base class in the composite class. like `class B{copyOfFunctionOfA(param){ a->functionOfA(param); }}` but i guess that's the only way to do it

Comment: Well, yes, that's what composition does :).

Answer (score 2):

Downcasting a pointer to a derived object if it actually points to an instance of a base class is undefined behavior. So you code is broken, anyway.